# Reading a list of data frames from a comma separated text file with comments, automate

Tags: r, iteration, dplyr

**NOTE:  THREE UPDATES HAVE BEEN MADE.  IDEAS ARE WELCOMED**

I have multiple text (.txt) files that are essentially lists of dataframes containing data for each one of several specimens.
Each set of data for each specimen begins with quotes ("") followed by a series of comments as strings ("string") separated by commas.
I need to separate out each set of data for each specimen, separate columns, and add new columns with information provided in the comments.

The data I need to extract is in the file name "file2.ext", and the specimen number which follows immediately after "Specimen Number" in the comments.

A sample of the data is below.

```
    ""
    "Test Method","file1.ext"
    "Sample I. D.","file2.ext"
    "Specimen Number","1"

    "A (unit1)","B (unit2)","C (unit3)","D (unit4)","E (%)"

    0.744,0.300,-0.046,0.197,-0.004
    0.903,0.400,0.038,0.239,0.003
    1.096,0.500,0.123,0.290,0.011
    1.314,0.600,0.207,0.348,0.018
    1.532,0.700,0.289,0.406,0.025
    1.776,0.800,0.373,0.471,0.033
    2.029,0.900,0.457,0.538,0.040
    2.282,1.000,0.541,0.605,0.047
    2.533,1.100,0.623,0.671,0.054
    2.783,1.200,0.707,0.738,0.062
    3.044,1.300,0.792,0.807,0.069
    3.319,1.400,0.876,0.880,0.076
    3.587,1.500,0.958,0.951,0.084


    ""
    "Test Method","file1.ext"
    "Sample I. D.","file2.ext"
    "Specimen Number","2"

    "A (unit1)","B (unit2)","C (unit3)","D (unit4)","E (%)"

    0.755,0.300,-0.055,0.218,-0.005
    0.918,0.400,0.030,0.265,0.003
    1.137,0.500,0.114,0.328,0.010
    1.377,0.600,0.198,0.397,0.017
    1.626,0.700,0.282,0.469,0.024
    1.874,0.800,0.365,0.541,0.031
    2.136,0.900,0.450,0.616,0.038
    2.400,1.000,0.533,0.692,0.045
    2.667,1.100,0.615,0.770,0.051
    2.935,1.200,0.699,0.847,0.058
    3.221,1.300,0.784,0.930,0.066
    3.505,1.400,0.867,1.011,0.072
    3.804,1.500,0.949,1.098,0.079
```

I have been able to construct usable dataframes, but need to know two things:
  1 -- is there a simpler read method that will allow me to read the file into a list?
  2 -- how can I automate the file read and construction of the final dataframes including the new columns?

1. Read text file into R using `scan()` results in a character vector that captures all the comments.

   ```
   character.vector <- scan("file_name.txt", "")
   ```
2. Find where in 'character.vector' the comment "Test Method" appears to identify each specimen using `grep()`

   ```
   specimen.vector <-grep(pattern= "Test Method", character.vector)
   > tm_test.2
   [1]    1  382  764 1146 1528 1910 2292 2674 3056 3438 3820 4202
   ```
3. Determine the indices required to subset 'character.vector' to build the new dataframe for a single specimen

   ```
   > specimen.start.at <- specimen.vector + 24
   > specimen.start.at
   [1]   25  406  788 1170 1552 1934 2316 2698 3080 3462 3844 4226

   > specimen.stop.at <- specimen.vector + 381
   > specimen.stop.at
   [1]  382  763 1145 1527 1909 2291 2673 3055 3437 3819 4201 4583
   ```

   There are 12 specimens with idices as indicated by the vectors 'specimen.start.at' and 'specimen.stop.at'.
   For example, the data (excluding comments) for specimen 1 spans 25:382 in 'character.vector'.
4. I did not figure out how to automatically extract data for each specimen, so I manually entered the indices as follows

   ```
   start <- specimen.start.at[specimen_number]
   finish <- specimen.stop.at[specimen_number]
   specimen.dataframe <- character.vector[start:finish] %>% strsplit(split = ",", fixed = TRUE) %>% ldply %>% tbl_df
   ```

The output for each specimen is a dataframe of 5 unlabeled columns.

```
          V1    V2    V3    V4    V5
    1  1.073 0.400 0.215 0.198 0.022
    2  1.315 0.500 0.299 0.242 0.031
    3  1.562 0.600 0.382 0.288 0.040
    4  1.840 0.700 0.466 0.339 0.049
    5  2.135 0.800 0.550 0.393 0.058
    6  2.438 0.900 0.634 0.449 0.066
    7  2.740 1.000 0.716 0.505 0.075
    8  3.046 1.100 0.800 0.561 0.084
    9  3.349 1.200 0.884 0.617 0.092
    10 3.660 1.300 0.969 0.674 0.101
    ..   ...   ...   ...   ...   ...
```

This is the output of the scan:

```
    [1] "Test Method"                      ",\"XXX"                          "YYY"                            
    [4] "test"                             "-"                               "Edit"                           
    [7] "ABB"                              "1-8-08.ext\""                    "Sample I. D."                   
    [10] ",\"1000"                         "gsm"                             "string"                       
    [13] "string"                          "ab"                              "20796-87.ext\""                 
    [16] "Specimen Number"                 ",\"1\""                          "A (unit1)"                       
    [19] ",\"B"                            "(unit2)\",\"C"                   "(unit3)\",\"D"                
    [22] "(unit4)\",\"E"                   "(%)\""                           "0.744,0.300,-0.046,0.197,-0.004"
    [25] "0.903,0.400,0.038,0.239,0.003"   "1.096,0.500,0.123,0.290,0.011"   "1.314,0.600,0.207,0.348,0.018"
```

Once I get the data frame to this point I would add several columns including specimen number, combine them into one combined data frame for this particular file, rename the columns, then build a list containing each file's data.  I think I may need to write a function that includes some version of the apply family of functions.  I'd like to stay away from for loops.

Rstudio was used.

Session Info

```
    > sessionInfo()
    R version 3.2.1 (2015-06-18)
    Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
    Running under: Windows 7 x64 (build 7601) Service Pack 1

    locale:
    [1] LC_COLLATE=English_United States.1252  LC_CTYPE=English_United States.1252    LC_MONETARY=English_United States.1252 LC_NUMERIC=C                          
    [5] LC_TIME=English_United States.1252    

    attached base packages:
    [1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

    other attached packages:
    [1] plyr_1.8.3  tidyr_0.2.0 dplyr_0.4.2

    loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
    [1] magrittr_1.5   R6_2.0.1       assertthat_0.1 parallel_3.2.1 DBI_0.3.1      tools_3.2.1    Rcpp_0.11.6
```

I want to thank you all ahead of time for you help.

**UPDATE**
Further investigation revealed that I can use `read.csv()` to read the text file, which gets the data into a data frame in R.

When I use the following code
`df <- read.csv("file.txt", sep = c(",", "\n"), header = F, stringsAsFactors= F)`
The resulting data frame looks like this

```
                 V1                          V2             V3           V4         V5
    1       Test Method                   file1.ext                                       
    2      Sample I. D.                   file2.ext                                       
    3   Specimen Number                           1                                       
    4         A (unit1)                   B (unit2)      C (unit3)    D (unit4)      E (%)
    5            -0.150                       0.000         -0.198       -0.006    -14.671
    6            -0.147                       0.100         -0.198       -0.006    -14.671
    7            -0.190                       0.300         -0.194       -0.007    -14.383
    8            -0.177                       0.400         -0.191       -0.007    -14.135
    9            -0.163                       0.500         -0.188       -0.006    -13.891
    203     Test Method                   file1.ext                                       
    204    Sample I. D.                   file2.ext                                       
    205 Specimen Number                           2                                       
    206       A (unit1)                   B (unit2)      C (unit3)    D (unit4)      E (%)
    207          -0.206                       0.000         -0.162       -0.008    -11.967
    208          -0.201                       0.100         -0.162       -0.008    -11.967
    209          -0.242                       0.300         -0.158       -0.010    -11.679
    210          -0.223                       0.400         -0.154       -0.009    -11.435
    211          -0.222                       0.500         -0.151       -0.009    -11.187
    212          -0.216                       0.600         -0.148       -0.009    -10.939
```

This only gets me part of the way.  My previous question stands.  Again, I want to thank everyone ahead of time.

**UPDATE -- CLARIFICATION**

I wanted to submit another update to clarify what kind of output I would like, so I decided to proceed manually with the following.  As mentioned previously, I know where the data begins for each specimen.  The indices are stored in a vector.

```
    specimen.record.start <- grep(pattern = "Test Method", data.file1$V1)
    > specimen.record.start
    [1]    1  363  726 1089 1452 1815 2178 2541 2904 3267 3630 3993
```

I used `slice()` for each of the twelve specimens, and the indices from `specimen.record.start` to choose the correct starting and stopping points for the slice.

```
    spec1.dfa <- data.file1 %>% slice(1:362)
    spec2.dfa <- data.file1 %>% slice(363:725)
    spec3.dfa <- data.file1 %>% slice(726:1088)
    spec4.dfa <- data.file1 %>% slice(1089:1451)
    spec5.dfa <- data.file1 %>% slice(1452:1814)
    spec6.dfa <- data.file1 %>% slice(1815:2177)
    spec7.dfa <- data.file1 %>% slice(2178:2540)
    spec8.dfa <- data.file1 %>% slice(2541:2903)
    spec9.dfa <- data.file1 %>% slice(2904:3266)
    spec10.dfa <- data.file1 %>% slice(3267:3629)
    spec11.dfa <- data.file1 %>% slice(3630:3992)
    spec12.dfa <- data.file1 %>% slice(3993:4355)
```

Then I built the dataframe that I wanted as follows:

```
    > spec1.dfa %>% filter(row_number() > 4) %>% rename(A = V1, B = V2, C = V3, D = V4, E = V5)         %>% mutate(specimen = 1, F = 1000, G = "cross", H = TRUE)
    Source: local data frame [358 x 9]

           A     B         C      D      E specimen    F         G      H
    1  0.744 0.300    -0.046  0.197 -0.004        1 1000     cross   TRUE
    2  0.903 0.400     0.038  0.239  0.003        1 1000     cross   TRUE
    3  1.096 0.500     0.123  0.290  0.011        1 1000     cross   TRUE
    4  1.314 0.600     0.207  0.348  0.018        1 1000     cross   TRUE
    5  1.532 0.700     0.289  0.406  0.025        1 1000     cross   TRUE
    6  1.776 0.800     0.373  0.471  0.033        1 1000     cross   TRUE
    7  2.029 0.900     0.457  0.538  0.040        1 1000     cross   TRUE
    8  2.282 1.000     0.541  0.605  0.047        1 1000     cross   TRUE
    9  2.533 1.100     0.623  0.671  0.054        1 1000     cross   TRUE
    10 2.783 1.200     0.707  0.738  0.062        1 1000     cross   TRUE
    ..   ...   ...       ...    ...    ...      ...  ...       ...    ...
```

Again, I would like to use something that will automitically insert the index numbers for each specimen record in the file.  Remember also that the text files I have contain multiple records specific to each specimen.  In this case there are twelve specimens, but other file may have more or fewer specimens.

Again, I want to thank everyone ahead of time.

**FINAL UPDATE -- SIMPLIFICATION, maybe**

I wanted to include one last update that shows a version of code that I used to achieve manually want I would really like to do with just calling a function.  As described previously, two vectors were saved to show the index as an integer for where data begins and ends for each specimen in the originally file.

```
    # > specimen.record.start
    # [1]    1  363  726 1089 1452 1815 2178 2541 2904 3267 3630 3993
    # > specimen.record.stop
    # [1]  362  725 1088 1451 1814 2177 2540 2903 3266 3629 3992 4355
    # > class(specimen.record.start)
    # [1] "integer"
    # > class(specimen.record.stop)
    # [1] "integer"
```

The previous update achieved the same thing except the index numbers were manually entered into the slice function. Below I replace the index numbers with a vector selection using brackets.  Ideally I would like to call a single function of a few lines of code to iterate through the slices.  I assigned each sliced data frame to its own name, but I should think that they can all be fed into a single empty data frame.  I'm just not sure how to do that.

```
    # Again to illustrate create the data frames manually.
    # The following is a set of data frames sliced from the orignial data

    # > spec1.dfb <- data.file1 %>% slice(specimen.record.start[1] : specimen.record.stop[1])
    # > spec2.dfb <- data.file1 %>% slice(specimen.record.start[2] : specimen.record.stop[2])
    # > spec3.dfb <- data.file1 %>% slice(specimen.record.start[3] : specimen.record.stop[3])
    # > spec4.dfb <- data.file1 %>% slice(specimen.record.start[4] : specimen.record.stop[4])
    # > spec5.dfb <- data.file1 %>% slice(specimen.record.start[5] : specimen.record.stop[5])
    # > spec6.dfb <- data.file1 %>% slice(specimen.record.start[6] : specimen.record.stop[6])
    # > spec7.dfb <- data.file1 %>% slice(specimen.record.start[7] : specimen.record.stop[7])
    # > spec8.dfb <- data.file1 %>% slice(specimen.record.start[8] : specimen.record.stop[8])
    # > spec9.dfb <- data.file1 %>% slice(specimen.record.start[9] : specimen.record.stop[9])
    # > spec10.dfb <- data.file1 %>% slice(specimen.record.start[10] : specimen.record.stop[10])
    # > spec11.dfb <- data.file1 %>% slice(specimen.record.start[11] : specimen.record.stop[11])
    # > spec12.dfb <- data.file1 %>% slice(specimen.record.start[12] : specimen.record.stop[12])
```

The sliced dataframes are then filtered using the pipeline operator `%>%` to pick up only the data and exclude the comments that are found at the beginning of each new set of specimen data.  I would also mutate those dataframes to add a few additional columns as shown in the previous update, and I would rename the columns labeled V1 through V5.  But for the sake of simplicity I only show the filters below.  Note that `row_number() > 4` indicates where the comments stop in the sliced data frames.  Again, ideally I would like to iterate filter over each data frame (or data set).

```
    # The following is a set of data frames filtered from the sliced data frames to exclue comment lines

    # > spec1.dfc <- spec1.dfb %>% filter(row_number() > 4)
    # > spec2.dfc <- spec2.dfb %>% filter(row_number() > 4)
    # > spec3.dfc <- spec3.dfb %>% filter(row_number() > 4)
    # > spec4.dfc <- spec4.dfb %>% filter(row_number() > 4)
    # > spec5.dfc <- spec5.dfb %>% filter(row_number() > 4)
    # > spec6.dfc <- spec6.dfb %>% filter(row_number() > 4)
    # > spec7.dfc <- spec7.dfb %>% filter(row_number() > 4)
    # > spec8.dfc <- spec8.dfb %>% filter(row_number() > 4)
    # > spec9.dfc <- spec9.dfb %>% filter(row_number() > 4)
    # > spec10.dfc <- spec10.dfb %>% filter(row_number() > 4)
    # > spec11.dfc <- spec11.dfb %>% filter(row_number() > 4)
    # > spec12.dfc <- spec12.dfb %>% filter(row_number() > 4)
```

Finally, all of the sliced and filtered data frames are row bound to create the final data frame with all the data.

```
    all.dfc <- rbind(spec1.dfc, spec2.dfc, spec3.dfc,
                     spec4.dfc, spec5.dfc, spec6.dfc,
                     spec7.dfc, spec8.dfc, spec9.dfc,
                     spec10.dfc, spec11.dfc, spec12.dfc)
    # > all.dfc
    # Source: local data frame [4,307 x 5]
    # 
    #       V1    V2     V3    V4     V5
    # 1  0.744 0.300 -0.046 0.197 -0.004
    # 2  0.903 0.400  0.038 0.239  0.003
    # 3  1.096 0.500  0.123 0.290  0.011
    # 4  1.314 0.600  0.207 0.348  0.018
    # 5  1.532 0.700  0.289 0.406  0.025
    # 6  1.776 0.800  0.373 0.471  0.033
    # 7  2.029 0.900  0.457 0.538  0.040
    # 8  2.282 1.000  0.541 0.605  0.047
    # 9  2.533 1.100  0.623 0.671  0.054
    # 10 2.783 1.200  0.707 0.738  0.062
    # ..   ...   ...    ...   ...    ...
```

To summarize, the data needs to be read into R, then the files need to divided (sliced) into parts corresponding to each separate specimen.  Each chunk of data is data unique to a specific test on a particular specimen.  The chunks (slices) then need to be filtered, and combined into one data frame with new columns added.  I've tried several looping functions from the apply family which all seem to elude me.  I am thinking about a function that does something like the following.

NOTE: The following is for illustration and is not actual code

```
    my_function <- function {
        my_data <- read(my_files)[i]
        my_final_data_frame <- my_data %>% slice(my_data) %>% filter(my_data) %>% mutate(my_data) %>% rename(my_data)
        repeat

    }
```

The `my_function` code is pseudocode, given only for illustration to explain a concept, and is not meant to show any understanding of the coding.  I'm not sure how exactly it would be written.  If anyone has any ideas, I welcome them.

Thanks again.

Comment: What do you mean by list of data frames? How can a flat file contain more than one data frame?

Comment: The data is just arranged so that it "looks" like it could be a list of data frames.  I was trying to be descriptive about what the text files contain.  There are some comments, and then some numbers all separated by commas.  Then there's another "chunk" that begins with comments, followed by some numbers separated by commas...so on and so on.  Each "chunk" is a unique set of data that I would like to extract.  As for flat files with multiple dataframes...I don't know if this comment is meant to be sarcasm or not.  All I know is that a list in R is a similar structure to the text files I have.

Comment: You've probably broke some word count record on [tag:r]

Comment: I was beginning to worry if I wrote too much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found that the following code solves the problem.  Please see the information provided in the question for details. The code extracts data from multiple forms or chunks corresponding to different data sets, then places them in separate data frames.  First, the files are found and read into a list and combined into one complete master data frame. Second, slice points (indices) are determined for start points and end points of the slice. Third, the slice is performed at the determined indices iterating through the indices, and placing the slices into a temporary list. Finally, the list of sliced indices are manipulated to add columns and rename columns.

```
    # load the required packages
      require(plyr)
      require(dplyr)
      require(tidyr)

    # find file names
      file.names <- list.files(pattern = ".txt")

    # read files
      read.files <- vector(mode = "list", length = length(file.names))
      read.files <- lapply(file.names, read.csv, sep = c(",", "\n"), header = F, stringsAsFactors = F)
      read.files.df <- ldply(read.files)

    # find indices
      index.slice.start <- grep(pattern = "Test Method", read.files.df$V1)
      minus_1 <- function(x) x - 1
      stop.vector <- sapply(index.slice.start, minus_1)
      stop.vector <- as.integer(sapply(index.slice.start, minus_1))
      index.slice.stop <- c(stop.vector[-1], nrow(read.files.df))

    # slice dataframes
      tmp <- vector(mode = "list", length = length(index.slice.start))

      for (i in 1:length(index.slice.start)) {
        r <- index.slice.start[i]
        p <- index.slice.stop[i]
        tmp[[i]] <- slice(read.files.df, index.slice.start[i]:index.slice.stop[i])

      }

    # Construct the dataframe
    all.df <- lapply(tmp, mutate, specimen = V2[3], sample = V2[2]) %>%
        lapply(filter, row_number() > 4) %>%
        lapply(rename, Variable1 = V1, Variable2 = V2, Variable3 = V3, Variable4 = V4, Variable5 = V5) %>%
        ldply %>%
        separate(sample, into = c("A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G"), sep = " ", extra = "merge") %>%
        rename(weight = A, gsm = B, null = C, agent = D, condition = E, direction = F, id = G) %>%
        select(-null, -gsm)
```